# WinForms Control Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web, browser

I am trying to read in the first description in the first row. However, for some reason my if statement is never becoming true. Here is the html code that has the class im trying to read from. I gave a picture of it. Below that is the actual code im running. There is a first page that I login to and then input the part number. This then takes me to this page where you see the html code in the picture. I then need to grab the description of the part number. I included a picture of the website I am grabbing the description from. In order to give you a better Idea of what's happening. Also, I have a web browser  component in my code that I am using. Can you point out why its not working? Thanks.

```
  var secondPage = webBrowser1.Document;
        foreach (HtmlElement element in secondPage.All)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("className") == "SE-Content-PartSearch-Grid-Row-Description")
            {
                messagebox.Show("Found it");
            }
        }
```

[ActualWebsite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVED4.png)

[HTMLCODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt4yR.png)

Comment: There is no `WebBrowser` Class in asp.net. You probably are using winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you put a breakpoint on the "if" statement. It will perhaps be easier to see what is going on if you modify the code slightly:

```
 var secondPage = webBrowser1.Document;
        foreach (HtmlElement element in secondPage.All)
        {
            String className = element.GetAttribute("className");
            if (className == "SE-Content-PartSearch-Grid-Row-Description")
            {
                messagebox.Show("Found it");
            }
        }
```